# How to calculate the reliability (probability of success) time-dependent equation given the probability of success for a one-hour time interval?

Tags: probability, reliability

I've encountered such a probability problem in a reliability engineering textbook:

A reliability function can be derived directly from probability theory.
Assume that the probability of successful operation for a one-hour time interval is 0.999. What is the probability of successful operation for a two-hour time interval, for a three-hour period, for a four-hour period, etc? Derive the time-dependent equation.

I couldn't get how to relate the probability of success of the first hour to the probability of success of the subsequent hours. Aren't they independent events and should, therefore, have different probabilities?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it that the statement, "the probability of successful operation for a one-hour time interval is $0.999.$," is intended to mean *any* one-hour interval.  Realistically, this may not be true, but this is just a simple example, the first example after the concept is introduced.

Your statement that independent events should have different probabilities is a little puzzling.  If the events are successive tosses of a coin, for example, they are all independent, and the probability that heads comes up is the same on every toss.  Independent, identically-distributed events are a staple of probability theory.

In this case, the answer is $f(t)=.999^t$, assuming independence.  We need independence in or to say, for example that the probability that it runs for two hours is the probability that it doesn't fail in the first hour times the probability that it doesn't fail in the second hour.

Answer (score 0):

The more common formula uses the **failure rate $\alpha$**
and links reliability to time with the formula $R = e^{-\lambda t}$

For your example, over a period of $24$ hours,
using the probability formula would yield a result of $P = 0.999^{24} \approx 0.976274$

while using the reliability formula, $R =e^{(-0.001\times24)} \approx 0.976286$

Not much of a difference, but it is the second formula that is generally used in reliability engineering.